# load another view controller when result is correct

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have the code submitting data to PHP script. The idea is that code inserts data to database. That happens successfully, the string returned would be "SUCCESSFUL", otherwise, "Failed". Now I want when the successful value returned, it loads another view saying thank you (label). How can I achieve this?

code:

```
(IBAction)saveDataAction:(id)sender {
    NSString *lEventTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var=%@",eventTitle.text];
    NSString *lEventDesc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var=%@",eventDescription.text];
   NSString *lEventCity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var=%@",eventCity.text];



    // Create your request string with parameter name as defined in PHP file
    NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title=%@&description=%@&city=%@",lEventTitle ,lEventDesc,lEventCity];

    myRequestString  = [myRequestString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"var=" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",myRequestString);
    // Create Data from request
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.xsysdevelopment.com/ios/form.php"]];
    // set Request Type
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    // Set content-type
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    // Set Request Body
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    // Now send a request and get Response
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
    // Log Response
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",response);

    if ([response rangeOfString:@"SUCCESSFUL"].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        //here??
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Do you want to prompt message on result ?

Comment: Yes that would be really good. and then when user clicks ok...it loads another seperate view i.e. the home view.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([response rangeOfString:@"SUCCESSFUL"].location != NSNotFound)
{
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Thank you" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
     [alert show];
     [alert release];
}
```

Here alert will be prompted now you can handle delegate method like this.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==1) //OK button pressed
    {
        //handle your another view here
         SampleViewController *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
         [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Make sure to implement `UIAlertViewDelegate` in your .h file.

References for more on presenting view.

1. [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)
2. [Modal View Controller Example](http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/)

Comment: Yes mate but loading the other view is what I don't know how to do and asked for help in. Any more explanation or something i can read online?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Navigation Based application use following

```
if ([response rangeOfString:@"SUCCESSFUL"].location != NSNotFound)
{
    SuccessViewController *objSVC = [[SuccessViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SuccessViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objSVC animated:YES];
}
else
{
    FailViewController *objFVC = [[FailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objFVC animated:YES];        
}
```

otherwise replace

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objFVC animated:YES];
```

with

```
[self presentModalViewController:objFVC animated:YES];
```